# puzzle function with fold in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am having a hard time trying to figure out how does this function works, and I need an explanation from an expert. Appreciate any help!

```
puzzle n x = scanr (\y acc -> (acc + y/acc)/2) 1 (replicate n x)
```

I tried running these:

```
--puzzle 10 2

--puzzle 10 5

--puzzle 10 36
```

and it gives me this output, respectively:

```
[1.414213562373095,1.414213562373095,1.414213562373095,1.414213562373095,1.414213562373095,1.414213562373095,1.4142135623746899,1.4142156862745097,1.4166666666666665,1.5,1.0]

[2.23606797749979,2.23606797749979,2.23606797749979,2.23606797749979,2.23606797749979,2.236067977499978,2.2360688956433634,2.238095238095238,2.3333333333333335,3.0,1.0]

[6.0,6.0,6.0,6.0,6.000000005333189,6.0002529841194185,6.055351744849479,6.872226737643129,10.222972972972974,18.5,1.0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes a list of n x-es like [x,x,x,x,x,..] (n times)

and then what it does is:

```
x1 = ( 1 +  x/1)/2
x2 = (x1 + x/x1)/2
x3 = (x2 + x/x2)/2
x4 = (x3 + x/x3)/2
```

and the result is `[xn,x(n-1),...,x2,x1]`

Comment: Or rather, the result is `[x1, x2, …]`, since the function used is actually `scanr`, not `foldr` as OP says.

Comment: Thank you guys for the informative comments and post!

Answer (score 2):

This function calculates a square root using Newton`s formula and stores all iteration results in list.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) is a Newton's method on wiki.

Storing process is based on definition of [scanr](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:scanr) function:

> scanr is similar to foldr, but returns a list
>   of successive reduced values from the right

Comment: Thanks for your help and explaining the scanr vs fold functions!